# OpenCV CvSVM.predict() decision function value

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I am training images with Bag of Words. However, every time I change the condition value in if statement or the sign, e.g. from `if(response<0)` to `if(response>0)` or from `if(response<-1)` to `if(response<-0.5)` I get different results `results.push_back(response)`. I could not figure out why this happens. I only change the condition, that's it. Please, help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
int i, j;
for(i=1;i<=img.cols-width;i=i+20){
    for(j=1;j<=img.rows-height;j=j+20){
        vector<KeyPoint>keypoints;
        Mat ROI = img(Rect(i, j, w, h)); 
        detector.detect(ROI,keypoints);
        if (keypoints.data()){
        Mat bowDescriptor2;
        bowDE.compute(img,keypoints,bowDescriptor2);
        evalData.push_back(bowDescriptor2);
        std::cout<<"SVM predicting..."<<std::endl;
        float response = svm.predict(bowDescriptor2,1); 
        results.push_back(response);
        std::cout<<response<<std::endl; 
        if(response<0)
        { 
            static CvScalar RED = {0, 0, 255};
            rectangle(img, Point(i,j), Point(i+w,j+h), RED, 3, 8, 0);
            cvNamedWindow( "result", 1 );
            imshow( "result", img );
        }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out where I made the mistake. The problem was that I could not use the same image as an input here `rectangle(img, Point(i,j), Point(i+w,j+h), RED, 3, 8, 0)`. Therefore, I read the image and defined it `img` as well as `img2` and then I replaced `img` with `img2` in `rectangle`.

Comment: If this fixed your problem, you should accept your answer :)